# programa sencillo en java me falla al responder el 3er if else

Tags: java, eclipse

hola amigos recien empiezo a aprender programacion y tengo un problema con un programa sencillo que estoy haciendo en java con eclipse ... dejo el codigo a ver si me pueden hechar una mano les re agradezco ya llevo 2 dias rompiendome la cabeza

se tiene que hacer solo con if y else

pareciera que funciona pero cuando estoy haciendo las pruebas el tercer if else falla

ya intente cambiarle el orden a ver si tenia que ver con eso y aun no doy con la solucion

de verdad quien me pueda ayudar se lo re agradezco

```
introducir el código aquí 




public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    /*
     * ) Una empresa requiere clasificar a las personas que se jubilaran en el año
     * 2002. Existen tres tipos de jubilaciones: por edad, por antigüedad joven y
     * por antigüedad adulta. Las personas adscritas a la jubilación por edad deben
     * tener 60 años o más y una antigüedad en su empleo de menos de 25 años. Las
     * personas adscritas a la jubilación por antigüedad joven deben tener menos de
     * 60 años y una antigüedad en su empleo de 25 años o más. Las personas
     * adscritas a la jubilación por antigüedad adulta deben tener 60 años o más y
     * una antigüedad en su empleo de 25 años o más. Determinar en qué tipo de
     * jubilación, quedara clasificada una persona.
     */

    // variables
    int edad = 0, TiempoEnEmpresa = 0;

    // datos que entran

    System.out.println("ingrese la edad del jubilado: ");
    edad = teclado.nextInt();

    System.out.println("ingrese el tiempo laboral del jubilado en la empresa: ");
    TiempoEnEmpresa = teclado.nextInt();

    // que procesa

    if (edad >= 60) 
        if (TiempoEnEmpresa >= 25) 
    {
            System.out.println("Su jubilacion corresponde a ser por Antiguedad Adulta");
    }

    else if (edad >= 60) 
        if (TiempoEnEmpresa < 25) 
    {
                System.out.println("Su jubilacion corresponde a ser por edad");
    }
    
    
    else if (edad < 60) 
        if (TiempoEnEmpresa >= 25) 
    {
            System.out.println("Su jubilacion corresponde a ser por Antiguedad Joven"); // aqui falla el programa y no responde
    }


    else 
    {
        System.out.println("No se jubila");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Cuando decís _falla_, ¿a qué te referís? Leé [ask]. Además, hacé que el título de tu pregunta sea más descriptivo.

Comment: pasa que las 2 primeras sentencias las pruebo una a una ingresando los valores para testear y se ejecutan bien, cuando pruebo la 3ra o la 4ta para que imprima en consola el resultado de estas, el programa queda como pausado y no reacciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te aconsejo que leas con detenimiento el enunciado del ejercicio.

Se te están planteando tres casos:

1. Las personas adscritas a la jubilación por edad deben tener 60 años o más y una antigüedad en su empleo de menos de 25 años
2. Las personas adscritas a la jubilación por antigüedad joven deben tener menos de 60 años y una antigüedad en su empleo de 25 años o más.
3. Las personas adscritas a la jubilación por antigüedad adulta deben tener 60 años o más y una antigüedad en su empleo de 25 años o más.

Entonces, ¿por qué no aplicar los tres casos tal cual? Para lograr lo que se está pidiendo no es necesario tener `if` anidados, podrías comparar ambas cosas en el mismo `if`  usando `&&`.

Veamos:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    
     /*
         * ) Una empresa requiere clasificar a las personas que se jubilaran en el año
         * 2002. Existen tres tipos de jubilaciones: por edad, por antigüedad joven y
         * por antigüedad adulta. Las personas adscritas a la jubilación por edad deben
         * tener 60 años o más y una antigüedad en su empleo de menos de 25 años. Las
         * personas adscritas a la jubilación por antigüedad joven deben tener menos de
         * 60 años y una antigüedad en su empleo de 25 años o más. Las personas
         * adscritas a la jubilación por antigüedad adulta deben tener 60 años o más y
         * una antigüedad en su empleo de 25 años o más. Determinar en qué tipo de
         * jubilación, quedara clasificada una persona.
     */

    // variables
    int edad = 0, TiempoEnEmpresa = 0;


    System.out.println("ingrese la edad del jubilado: ");
    edad = teclado.nextInt();

    System.out.println("ingrese el tiempo laboral del jubilado en la empresa: ");
    TiempoEnEmpresa = teclado.nextInt();

    /*
         *1. Las personas adscritas a la jubilación por edad deben tener
         *   60 años o más y una antigüedad en su empleo de menos de 25 años
    */ 
    if (edad >= 60 && TiempoEnEmpresa < 25) 
    {
        System.out.println("Caso 1: Su jubilacion corresponde a ser por Antiguedad Adulta");         
        
    /*
         * 2. Las personas adscritas a la jubilación por antigüedad joven deben tener 
         *    menos de 60 años y una antigüedad en su empleo de 25 años o más.            
    */            
    } 
    else if (edad < 60 && TiempoEnEmpresa >= 25) 
    {
            System.out.println("Caso 2: Su jubilacion corresponde a ser por edad");
        
    /*
         * 3. Las personas adscritas a la jubilación por antigüedad adulta deben tener
         *    60 años o más y una antigüedad en su empleo de 25 años o más. 
    */        
        
    } 
    else if (edad >= 60 && TiempoEnEmpresa >= 25) 
    {
              System.out.println("Caso 3: Su jubilacion corresponde a ser por Antiguedad Joven"); 

    }
    else 
    {
               System.out.println("No se jubila");
    }              
}
```

Comment: comprendido totalmente, justo hoy estaba aprendiendo a usar **&&** en las condicionales, ya me estaba acercando jeje, mil gracias de verdad estoy poniendole ganas a este aprendizaje, un saludo y un fuerte abrazo

Comment: @NestorRincones me alegro de que te haya servido. Un saludo y buen aprendizaje.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está al momento de realizar las condicionales; la condición es clara con respecto a la edad:
Condición 1: La edad es mayor o igual a 60
Condición 2: La edad es menor que 60

No hay más condiciones, en tu caso realizas 4 condiciones para tu edad por ello el programa no sabe que hacer.
Para el caso de años de trabajo en la empresa, también existen 2 condiciones y esto depende de la edad, es decir será una condición interna.
El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
        int edad = 0, TiempoEnEmpresa = 0;

        // datos que entran

        System.out.println("ingrese la edad del jubilado: ");
        edad = teclado.nextInt();

        System.out.println("ingrese el tiempo laboral del jubilado en la empresa: ");
        TiempoEnEmpresa = teclado.nextInt();
        

        if (edad >= 60) {
            if (TiempoEnEmpresa >= 25)             
                System.out.println("Su jubilacion corresponde a ser por Antiguedad Adulta");            
            else
                System.out.println("Su jubilacion corresponde a ser por Edad");
        } 
        else{ 
            if (TiempoEnEmpresa >= 25)    
                System.out.println("Su jubilacion corresponde a ser por Antiguedad Joven");
            else     
                System.out.println("No se jubila");
        }
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias por esta respuesta, me cuesta un poco mas entenderla que la otra pero al final la comprendo, espero poder desarrollar esa habilidad de analisis a la hora de crear condicionales. espero que no halla sido molestia haberse tomado el tiempo de responder lo valoro mucho

Comment: No es molestia amigo, en realidad la respuesta que da @A. Cedano es mejor, más aún si recién estás comenzando en la programación; lo que debes sacar de estas respuestas es que existe más de una forma de resolver un ejercicio por más simple que sea